# Npgsql and paged datagridview

Tags: datagridview, npgsql

I have managed to get my head around performing SQL commands succesfully in npgsql on visual basic 2010, but now I am having great difficulty in figuring out how to do a paged datagrid view.

Does anyone have a really simple example for visual studio (visual basic 2010) of using a simple datagridview on form, linked using npgsql to a large datatable?

Say there is a table called users, with a fiew fields in it, and millions of rows.

I know that normally you would not want to make a user scroll through millions of rows, and should offer filtering, but i want to be able to have a datagridview displayed (with filtering options on the form which I can handle) and if the user scrolls down, only the records needed are being loaded.

My problem is just not having a clue where to start, I have seen MS examples, but they do no use npgsql, and I have no idea how npgsql works in this area.

So a simple example for a paged data grid view with npgsql would be a massive help - then once I know the basic commands in npgsql etc, I can expand it/alter it to suit requirements.

Its just a learning experiment - I dont like the idea of a datagridview that is loading all rows into memory - its not expandable...

Answer (score 1):

Never mind - figured it out.

Did not notice the

Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter()

which makes it possible to use a MS example, with the rest of the info altered to suit personal need.